# angular routing - navigate to same component with additional params without destroying the component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have a routing setting like this

```
{
    path: '',
    component: BaseCmp,
    children: [
        { path: 'list', component: ListCmp },
        {
            path: 'list/:itemId',
            component: ListItemCmp,
        },
        {
            path: 'list/:itemId/:subNavItemId',
            component: ListItemCmp,
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm selecting an Item from the ListCmp and get navigated to for example 'list/123'

In the ListCmp Constructor/OnInit I'm fetching some data with the :itemId and it returns a list of SubNavItems, from which the id of the first SubNavItem should be added as params (for routerLinkActive to highlight and other fetching purposes).

```
constructor(route:ActivatedRoute, http:HttpClient, router:Router){
   let id = route.params.itemId
   http.get(.../id).subscribe(list => {
        // add id of first item of list to params
        this.router.navigate(['list', id, list[0].id, {replaceUrl:true}]
   })
}
```

This will cause the destruction of the current ListItemCmp and instantiate a new ListItemCmp. How can I prevent that? I've tried the location.go() method but that won't trigger the routerLinkActive

Comment: `'list/:itemId/:subNavItemId'` should be a child of `'list/:itemId'` : because of that, your routing creates two instances of a same class, but has to destroy them to route away to the URL. Make it a child of the first route, then your component should not be destroyed anymore.

Comment: thanks, I did just that, if you post a reply I can check it off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment, your error was coming from the fact that your routes were siblings instead of parents : by routing away from the first sibling, you were destroying it to create the other sibling.

With parent routes, the parent will stay (because it contains a router outlet and can't disappear), while the child will be appended to the parent, meaning the parent doesn't get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use query params instead of hard routing

```
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    let id = route.params.itemId
    http.get(.../id).subscribe(list => {
        // add id of first item of list to params
        this.router.navigate(['list', id], { queryParams: { subNavItemId: list[0].id } })
    })
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(query => {
      if (query['params']['subNavItemId']) {
        // perform some action
      }
    });
  }
```

In your router you can now remove "list/:itemId/:subNavItemId"

```
{
    path: '',
    component: BaseCmp,
    children: [
        { path: 'list', component: ListCmp },
        {
            path: 'list/:itemId',
            component: ListItemCmp,
        },
        // you can remove below route
// {
         //    path: 'list/:itemId/:subNavItemId',
         //    component: ListItemCmp,
       //  }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, that provides a workaround for the issue.